# How to run a spec file which consists of 'describe','it, methods using cucumber?

Tags: rspec, cucumber, jruby

I am working on integrating rspec with cucumber, i am trying to run a spec file 
which consists of 'describe','it' methods from cucumber. Cucumber is failing to execute describe,it methods, 
so i am trying to run the whole spec file from cucumber, anyone have suggestions on how to do this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Cucumber and RSpec are completely different tools, you can't expect one to run stuff written for the other!

Comment: The framework that we are working is in RSpec, we want to change this to cucumber.

Comment: You might want to take a look at running Gherkin (the language Cucumber uses) specs inside rspec then, e.g. by using [rspec-turnip](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip).

Comment: Why do you want to change to Cucumber?